# Get an image to display when hovering over an div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div tag that looks like this:

```html
<div id="left">
    <p class="h1">EXCPERIENCES</p>

    <p class="describe">Websites, Ecommerce, Mobile Apps & <br />Installations</p>

    <img id="img1"src="ski.jpg" alt="ski">

</div>
```

I want the image (ski) to display when i hover over

```html
<div id="left">
```

and when I don't have 
the mouse over the "left" div the image should disappear.

This div called "left" is an childbox in a bigger parent box called "middle", when I hover the "left" div the picture should be visible over the entire "middle" which is the parent.

I have tried different solutions bust most of them is for a `<span>` or an `<a>` tag.

I can explain better if necessary and I don't need to show css, I'm only looking for a solution on how to do it, I'm familiar with JS.

> *to summarize* I want a picture to be invisible until hovering over the box/div called "left" *I don't want the picture to show only when
>   hovering the text*, and when hovering the "left" the picture should be
>   shown and displayed, the rest I can figure out myself.

Comment: Does this help? [html javascript show image hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20166877/html-javascript-show-image-hover)

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize css :hover for this. Pure css solution:

```
#img1 {
 display: none;
}

#left:hover #img1 {
 display: block;
}
```

Comment: Hi! that worked perfectly fine! can i just add #left .img1{} in the CSS to style the image? like rezise it and reposition it?

Comment: Hi, yes you can use it keeping the img, I'll update my answer.

Comment: I used the second one THX dude, really worked out great! =D

Comment: Also one more thing, now the image is desplayed as default when i load the page, is there somehow possible to make the images not visiblke when loading page at first?

Comment: Well the image is set to display: none initially so it shouldn't be displayed on first load unless you hover over that div. Can you check if you have some old code left or sth. which might affect this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <div id="left">
       <p class="h1">EXPERIENCES</p>

       <p class="describe">Websites, Ecommerce, Mobile Apps & <br />Installations</p>

       <img id="img1"src="ski.jpg" alt="ski">
    </div>

<script>
    document.getElementById("left").onmouseover = function() {showImage()};
    document.getElementById("left").onmouseout = function() {hideImage()};

    function showImage() {
      document.getElementById("img1").setAttribute("style", "visibility: hidden");
    }

    function hideImage() {
      document.getElementById("img1").setAttribute("style", "visibility: visible");
    }
</script>

</html>
```

This code should work, also I fixed your spelling mistake regarding the word "experiences". Enjoy bud :)

Comment: Hi! this worked but with reverse for some reason, when i hover with the mouse over "left" the image gets hidden and when not hovering it shows.

Comment: I reversed the function (changed place on vidibility) to get it working, but now the image is shown when i load the page and when i hover once and then hover out it is not visible, is there any fix that the image is non visible from the start?

Comment: You could give it a the `display: none` css property via javascript onLoad, it should set the image to be invisible when the page loads.

Comment: `var onWindowLoaded = () => {
    var theDiv = document.getElementById("left");
    theDiv.setAttribute("style", "display: none");
}`


`window.addEventListener("load", onWindowLoaded);`

This should do the trick :)